# ¿Cómo solucionar el error System.FormatException en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Porqué me sale el siguiente error?:

> System.FormatException:'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato
>   correcto.'.

Lo que estoy haciendo es validar en mi textbox (**txtIngresarMonto**), que solo se ingrese números del 15 hasta el 119 sin decimales, mediante el evento **KeyPress**, este es el ***código completo*** que me valida que solo se ingrese:

> 1. **Números enteros.**
> 2. **Que solo se ingrese valores del 15 hasta el 119.**
> 3. **Admita la tecla BackSpace.**

```
private void TxtIngresarMonto_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back) && !(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (int.Parse(txtIngresarMonto.Text) < 15 || int.Parse(txtIngresarMonto.Text) > 115)
        {
            lblMSG.Visible = true;
            lblMSG.Text = "Fuera de rango";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMSG.Visible = false;
        }
    }

}
```

y cuando ejecuto e ingreso un **valor** que **no cumple con la condición**, como por **ejemplo** el número **1** me aparece el siguiente error en esta línea del código:

```
if (int.Parse(txtIngresarMonto.Text) < 15 || int.Parse(txtIngresarMonto.Text) > 115)
```

[image: Error System.FormatException]

¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?.

Comment: Eso lo que quiere decir es que el string no puede ser convertido en numero, por ejemplo "a" no se convertir. Las opciones que tienes son 1) usar `TryParse()`, 2) Poner tu código en un bloque Try/Catch, 3) Validar tu mismo el input. Te recomiendo TryParse https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema es el evento que estás utilizando para comprobar el valor del `TextBox`. Usas `KeyPress` e intentas comprobar el valor de `txtIngresarMonto`, pero la realidad es que en el momento en el que se dispara este evento, el valor de la tecla pulsada aún no ha sido añadida al `TextBox`. Por eso, cuando pulsas un `1` al principio te da el error, porque está intentando convertir a `int` una cadena vacía.

Te recomiendo que en lugar de `KeyPress`, utilices [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), así como [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) para filtrar los caso de `TextBox` vacío o con caracteres que no sean dígitos. Aqui te pongo el código de ejemplo:

```
private void txtIngresarMonto_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int valor;
    if (int.TryParse(txtIngresarMonto.Text,out valor))
    {
        if (valor < 15 || valor > 115)
        {
            lblMSG.Visible = true;
            lblMSG.Text = "Fuera de rango";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMSG.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblMSG.Visible = true;
        lblMSG.Text = "Valor no válido";
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Pikoh, si me funcionó.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar a hacerlo de varias maneras.

1- Utilizar el método Parse de la clase Int32:

```
try{
    if (Int32.Parse(txtIngresarMonto.Text) < 15 || Int32.Parse(txtIngresarMonto.Text) > 115){...}
catch(Exception e)  //Añado el try catch por seguridad
{...}
```

2- Utilizar el método TryParse de int

```
int res;
int res2;
if(int.TryParse(txtIngresarMonto.Text, out res)) { //Comprobamos que se puede convertir a int, si se puede, el resultado lo "mete" en res
    if(res <15 and res>115){...}
}else{
    MessageBox.Show("No es un número", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

En la opción 1 se convierte el valor del TextBox y se compara su valor, si no se puede convertir, entramos en la parte del catch.

En la opción 2, lo primero se comprueba que se pueda pasar a entero el texto del TextBox y después, si se ha podido convertir, comprobamos si es mayor o menor que lo deseado

Además, como te ha dicho @Pikoh en su respuesta, tienes que cambiar el evento desde el que llamas a este código, ya que KeyPress no ha escrito todavía en el textbox, tienes que usar el TextChanged para tener el texto cambiado al entrar al código.

Comment: Ya he editado el código haciendo referencia a tu respuesta para el tema del evento que dispara, estoy de acuerdo con que tiene que ser TextChanged. He puesto el try catch en la primera opción porque cuando el texto sea vacío (que borre todo el textBox), si no controlas esa excepción te va a "petar el programa".

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte @Pablo